# How to give inputs to a website using python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

hi all I am new to python. please help me with this requirement.

```
http://www.example.com/ratings/ratings-rationales.jsp?date=true&result=true
```

In this link, I have to choose date first, then the rating company will list its publications as links. Now i wanted to search a link that contains a word of my interest say "stable". I have tried the following using python 3.4.2

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests

url = "http://www.example.com/ratings/ratings-rationales.jsp?date=true&result=true"   
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

example_links = lambda tag: getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and 'stable' in tag.get_text().lower() and 'href' in tag.attrs
results = soup.find_all(example_links)
result_links = [urljoin(url, tag['href']) for tag in results]
print (result_links)
```

This is not printing anything. Iam seeing below as result

```
>>>
[]
```

Obviously Iam not giving date as input.
 1. How to input from and to dates as **today's date** ?  (Obviously to check periodically for updates of the links containing a word of interest, which will be question for later time)
 For example after giving from date: 31-12-2014       to date: 31-12-2014 as inputs

is the output I need as hyperlink.

Any suggestion will be much useful. Thanks in advance

Here is the updated code still Iam not able to get the result. `>>> []` is the output

```
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests

#Getting the current date
today = datetime.today()

#For the sake of brevity some parameters are missing on the payload
payload = {
    'selArchive': 1,
    'selDay': 31, 
    'selMonth': 12, 
    'selYear': 2014,
    'selDay1': 31, 
    'selMonth1': 12, 
    'selYear1': 2014,
    'selSector': '',
    'selIndustry': '',
    'selCompany': ''
}

example_url = "http://www.example.com/
r = requests.post(example_url, data=payload)    
rg = requests.get(example_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rg.content)

crisil_links = lambda tag: getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and 'stable' in tag.get_text().lower() and 'href' in tag.attrs   
results = soup.find_all(example_links)
result_links = [urljoin(url, tag['href']) for tag in results]
print (result_links)
```

Comment: you should consider that dates cannot be equal, and also that they cannot differ in more than one month.

Comment: But in the website I gave both as same ( 31 dec 2014).
I see only this condition and two more conditions but not same date condition
`if(todate-fromdate>2678400000){
      alert('The Date range can not exceeds one month');
      document.frmCrisil.selDay.focus();
      return false;
        }`

Comment: Yep, but when you try to click a range of dates with the same dates, an error message is displayed.

Comment: I am not sure I understood. If you try to key in today's date it will not display anything because there are no updates yet for today. but if you any date (otherthan sunday) you can see the results. Once again sorry if Iam taking up your time. So same date is valid i think. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right...I was trying on a date from the future

Comment: Please check the code of the answer

Comment: Hi, excellent. This is exactly I wanted. Thank you soooo much. Just a small modification is need for readability purpose.
I just wanted to print text first `4 Genius Minds: 'CRISIL B-/Stable' assigned to bank debt` --> its html next `http://www.crisil.com/Ratings/RatingList/RatingDocs/_Genius_Minds_December_31_2014_RR.html`. Can you plz help on this last step

Comment: You will only need to modify the findall condidion with the limit.   http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-limit-argument parameter and in the lambda expression just check the text matches your criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing a POST instead of a GET for this particular site ([this link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) on how to form a post request with parameters).

Check this example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

#Getting the current date
today = datetime.today()

#Here I'm only passing from and to dates (current date) and the industry parameter
payload = {
    'selDay': 31, 
    'selMonth': 12, 
    'selYear': 2014,
    'selDay1': 31, 
    'selMonth1': 12, 
    'selYear1': 2014,
    'selIndustry': '',
    'txtPhrase': '',
    'txtInclude': '',
    'txtExclude': '',
    'selSubServices': 'ALL',
    'selServices': 'all',
    'maxresults': 10,
    'pageno': 1,
    'srchInSrchCol': '01',
    'sortOptions': 'date',
    'isSrchInSrch': '01',
    'txtShowQuery': '01',
    'tSearch': 'Find a Rating',
    'txtSearch': '',
    'selArchive': 1,
    'selSector': 148,
    'selCompany': '',
    'x': 40,
    'y': 11,
}

crisil_url = "http://www.crisil.com/ratings/ratings-rationales.jsp?result=true&Sector=true"
r = requests.post(crisil_url, data=payload)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

crisil_links = lambda tag: getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and 'stable' in tag.get_text().lower() and 'href' in tag.attrs
results = soup.find_all(crisil_links)
result_links = [urljoin(crisil_url, tag['href']) for tag in results]
print (result_links)
```

You will need to check the ids of the industries you are filtering, so be sure to check them via Inspect Element, selecting a the select box of industries on the browser.

After that, you will get the response and do the parsing via BeautifulSoup, as you are doing now.

**Checking periodically:**
To check this periodically you should consider crontab if using Linux/Unix or a Scheduled task if using Windows.

Comment: maybe adding an actual example of a post request instead of a link would be better

Comment: @avenet Can you also suggest how to get the response from website to which we passed the inputs. Below is the way i have used. But nothing resulting
`r = requests.post(crisil_url, data=payload)  
rg = requests.get(crisil_url)   
soup = BeautifulSoup(rg.content)`

Comment: What's the result? I can get the result from the request, but it's the empty list of results, because some parameters from the list I sent you are missing, so you need to provide them all

Comment: BTW, this sites take a long time (5 or 6 seconds) to process your POST request, so you should consider this!!

Comment: yeah, little slow. Can you please guide me how to find other parameters for which i need to provide values or whatever you has sent is the full set. I found this section. Pardon me for not knowing html
     `var day = document.frmCrisil.selDay.value;  
        var month = document.frmCrisil.selMonth.value;
         month = month-1;
        var year = document.frmCrisil.selYear.value;

                  var day1 = document.frmCrisil.selDay1.value;  
        var month1 = document.frmCrisil.selMonth1.value;
         month1 = month1-1;
        var year1 = document.frmCrisil.selYear1.value;`

Comment: Using jQuery, open the Javascript console on your browser with the site open and just do:  $("[name=<parameter_name>]"). Eg:$("[name=selDay]"). On the results, you will see the html for this particular element, and that will give you insights on how to do it.

Comment: Hi, If i understand correctly, If Iam selecting dates I need not to give sector industry or company name as my intention is to list all the results between those dates. I did the following, but still seeing empty [] as result. In fact it should result with some output.
'payload = {
    'selDay': 31, 
    'selMonth': 12, 
    'selYear': 2014,
    'selDay1': 31, 
    'selMonth1': 12, 
    'selYear1': 2014,
#    'selSector': 153,
#    'selIndustry': 187,
#    'selCompany': '3F Industries Limited'
}'

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it's all send anyway because it is part of the form. But you can set them as empty fields.

Comment: Hi, I had set the other fields as zero. still seeing no result. Can plz help me to finish this last step.
payload = {
    'selDay': 31, 
    'selMonth': 12, 
    'selYear': 2014,
    'selDay1': 31, 
    'selMonth1': 12, 
    'selYear1': 2014,
    'selSector': 0,
    'selIndustry': 0,
    'selCompany': 0
}

Comment: Try setting them as the empty string.

Comment: 'selSector': '',
    'selIndustry': '',
    'selCompany': ''}
Still empty [] is the result.
I have another doubt. Is this the correct way of reading the website for which I have posted the inputs
`r = requests.post(crisil_url, data=payload)
rg = requests.get(crisil_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rg.content)`

Comment: Yes, it's the correct way. Also, set on the payload 'selArchive':'1' (it represents the date wise search)

Comment: Still `>>> [] ` is the result. If u don't mind can I post the entire code here so that u can take a look?